# ArrayList de clase repite el mismo valor

Tags: java, arraylist

Tengo un `ArrayList` de clase, al cargarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
ArrayList<Diccionario>  puertaHabitacion= new ArrayList<Diccionario>();
Diccionario puertaHab=new Diccionario();
puertaHab.setClave("Puerta Cocina");
puertaHab.setValor("Cocina");
puertaHabitacion.add(puertaHab);

puertaHab.setClave("Puerta Estudio");
puertaHab.setValor("Estudio");
puertaHabitacion.add(puertaHab);

puertaHab.setClave("Puerta Baño");
puertaHab.setValor("Baño");
puertaHabitacion.add(puertaHab);

puertaHab.setClave("Puerta Principal");
puertaHab.setValor("Principal");
puertaHabitacion.add(puertaHab);
```

En este ejemplo en concreto e ingresado 4 objetos de tipo Diccionario en el `ArrayList` sin embargo al imprimir el `ArrayList`completo se repiten los últimos valores ingresados, es decir en todos los valores me sale como claves "Puerta Principal" y como valores "Principal"

Porque se da este error y como puedo solucionar este inconveniente

Comment: Porque estas trabajando sobre un objeto y esto hace que siempre sea el mismo. Tendrías que crear un objeto nuevo por cada posición.

Comment: Existe alguna otra forma de hacerlo? el problema es que estoy generando código mediante Acceleo, y al hacer esto aumentario las lineas de código generadas.

Comment: Podrías usar un bucle o una función que cada vez que te añadiera un nuevo Diccionario al ArrayList.

Comment: Acabo de hacerlo con un bucle y me ha ayudado a resolver el problema, muchas gracias por tu ayuda, si puedes postearlo como respuesta para poder votar.

Answer (score 5):

El problema viene porque usas el mismo objeto `Diccionario` y esto hace que cuando cambies un valor de este se cambie en todos los sitios.

Para solucionar esto tienes que crear un nuevo objeto `Diccionario` antes de añadir nuevos valores.

```
ArrayList<Diccionario>  puertaHabitacion = new ArrayList<Diccionario>();
Diccionario puertaHab = new Diccionario();
puertaHab.setClave("Puerta Cocina");
puertaHab.setValor("Cocina");
puertaHabitacion.add(puertaHab);

puertaHab=new Diccionario();
puertaHab.setClave("Puerta Estudio");
puertaHab.setValor("Estudio");
puertaHabitacion.add(puertaHab);

puertaHab=new Diccionario();
puertaHab.setClave("Puerta Baño");
puertaHab.setValor("Baño");
puertaHabitacion.add(puertaHab);

puertaHab=new Diccionario();
puertaHab.setClave("Puerta Principal");
puertaHab.setValor("Principal");
puertaHabitacion.add(puertaHab);
```

Creo que el nombre de la variable puedes mantenerlo, pero necesita que la vuelvas a inicializar.

En caso de querer hacerlo en bucle sería algo así:

```
 ArrayList<Diccionario>  puertaHabitacion = new ArrayList<Diccionario>();
 Diccionario puertaHab;
 int cantidad_puerta = 4;
 String[] clave_puerta = ["Puerta Cocina","Puerta Estudio","Puerta Baño","Puerta Principal"];
 String[] valor_puerta = ["Cocina","Estudio","Baño","Principal"];
 for(int i = 0; i < cantidad_puerta; i++)
 {
    puertaHab = new Diccionario();
    puertaHab.setClave(clave_puerta[i]);
    puertaHab.setValor(valor_puerta[i]);
    puertaHabitacion.add(puertaHab);
 }
```